# Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "policy". DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

OK so I'm trying to validate the following XML file with the following DTD, but I keep getting the error `Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "policy".`

The XML file is shown as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE policies SYSTEM "langs.dtd">
<policies>
<description>Policies taken out in January</description>
<policy type="contents">
<policy-number>1234557</policy-number>
<policy-holder>A. Liu</policy-holder>
</policy>
<policy type="buildings">
<policy-number>1234558</policy-number>
<policy-holder>C. Jones</policy-holder>
</policy>
<report-date>01/01/2008</report-date>
</policies>
```

The DTD file is below:

```
<!ELEMENT policies (description, policy+, report-date)>
<!ELEMENT policy (policy-number, policy-holder)>
<!ELEMENT policy-number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT policy-holder (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT report-date (#PCDATA)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no attribute declared in your DTD. If you want your XML to validate properly, you will need to declare the `type` attribute on the policy element that way (for example):

```
<!ATTLIST policy
          type       CDATA    #IMPLIED >
```

There are other possibilities with attribute, to bring you a first view you can have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp