# XML Attributes declaration

Tags: xml, types, attributes, element

27  Attribute "style" must be declared for element type "table".

What does this mean?

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>LastName</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>phonenumber</th>
<th>PhysicianName</th>
<th>Insurance</th>
<th>REASON</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835161/attribute-type-must-be-declared-for-element-type-policy-dtd Does your document reference a DTD in a DOCTYPE declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Your first line

> 27 Attribute "style" must be declared for element type "table".

is likely the output a validator that is checking your markup against a schema that does not allow a `style` attribute on the `table` element.  Remove the `style` attribute to eliminate the error.  Be sure to close the open `table` tag too.  Finally, if this is HTML, consider styling via non-inlined CSS instead.